# Google Speech To Text Dialog For IOS (Flutter)

Tags: ios, flutter, speech-to-text, google-speech-to-text-api, voice-to-text

Is there any way to implement Google's **Speech To Text** Dialog in **Flutter for IOS** or even for **IOS native**

I successfully implemented it for Android through native code in Flutter. but don't know if it's even possible for iOS in Flutter directly or by using native code.

[image]